# Floppy is read but not written on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mount, format, floppy

I'm trying to mount a floppy drive (tested on windows98, it works) but I still encounter mounting errors.

I enabled the floppy drive for my user - which has been disabled -  and installed udisks.

When I mount it as /dev/fd0, I can't read/write onto the drive, while if I mount as /media/floppy/ I can read the drive but I can't write onto it (read only mode; disk is enabled for writing).

Which do you suggest to try for mount (and actually reformat) the floppy?
I'll post what I try for understand where is my fault :)

Tried to mount with

```
udisks --mount /dev/fd0
```

It says

```
Mount failed: Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: block device /dev/fd0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/fd0,
missing codepage or helper program, or other error
In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail or so
```

And with

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/floppy
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/fd0 /mnt/floppy
```

It says

```
mount: secondo mtab, /dev/fd0 è montato su /media/username/disk2
```

When I want unmount I use the GUI or

```
sudo umount /dev/fd0
```

and if I try to format with

```
sudo mformat -f 1440 A:
```

It says

```
plain_io: Input/output errors
buffer_flush: short write
```

With automount (GUI mode), located at /media/username/disk2, I can read disk, but can't write on it.

Somewhere is suggested to rollback udisks package to an older version which has a better handling of floppies.

Comment: - What do you mean by "Sometimes it crashes"?
- Why are you sure the floppies are actually working?
- What do you mean by "Neither... mounting point works"?
- What version are you on? Not everybody knows what the latest Lubuntu is like now, let alone if this question gets older and older...

Comment: I've been too cryptic, now should be a little clear... if any doubt/request for info or logs, let me know and I'll try =)

Comment: What commands are you using to mount it?

Comment: I tried with udisks --mount /dev/fd0 but seem not to work... I read somewhere the udisks recent package has problem with floppies... can you confirm it?

Answer (score 0):

What size is the floppy disk? e.g 3.5"   8"?

For 3.5" Floppy Disks, There is a little black switch on the back of the floppy, make sure that switch is covering a little hole. If not, slide it so that it is.

The switch decides on weather the disk is read / write, or only read.